# How to add keys to an existing multiple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the bellow multiple array:

```
 array:4 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        0 => "some content"
        1 => "some content"
        2 => "some content"
        3 => "some content"
        4 => "some content"
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        0 => "some content"
        1 => "some content"
        2 => "some content"
        3 => "some content"
        4 => "some content"
      ]
      2 => array:6 [▼
        0 => "some content"
        1 => "some content"
        2 => "some content"
        3 => "some content"
        4 => "some content"
        5 => "some content"
      ]
      3 => array:5 [▼
        0 => "some content"
        1 => "some content"
        2 => "some content"
        3 => "some content"
        4 => "some content"
      ]
    ]
```

How can I add keys to this array so it looks like:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    title => "some content"
    subtitle => "some content"
    somekey => "some content"
    somekey2 => "some content"
    somekey3 => "some content"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    title => "some content"
    subtitle => "some content"
    somekey => "some content"
    somekey2 => "some content"
    somekey3 => "some content"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    title => "some content"
    subtitle => "some content"
    somekey => "some content"
    somekey2 => "some content"
    somekey3 => "some content"
    somekey4 => "some content"
  ]
  3 => array:5 [▼
    title => "some content"
    subtitle => "some content"
    somekey => "some content"
    somekey2 => "some content"
    somekey3 => "some content"
  ]
]
```

Is there any way to do it without for loop?

There isn't any way to add keys before because I don't know how many arrays will be create.

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: foreach loop, build a new array

Comment: Are the there always 5 items in each subarray?

Comment: Thank you. I thought maybe there's a way without foreach loop. The items   is 5 or 6.

Comment: sigh, the problem with a `foreach` loop is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a combination of [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to iterate through the array and combine a preset list of keys with the values of each nested array.

> array_walk — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array
>   array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```php
$array=array(
  array('some content1','some content','some content','some content','some content'),
  array('some content2','some content','some content','some content','some content'),
  array('some content3','some content','some content','some content','some content'),
  array('some content4','some content','some content','some content','some content')
);    

$keys=array('title','subtitle','somekey','somekey2','somekey3');

function combine(&$v,$i,$keys) {
  $v=array_combine($keys,$v);
}

array_walk($array,'combine',$keys);

print_r($array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => some content1
            [subtitle] => some content
            [somekey] => some content
            [somekey2] => some content
            [somekey3] => some content
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => some content2
            [subtitle] => some content
            [somekey] => some content
            [somekey2] => some content
            [somekey3] => some content
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => some content3
            [subtitle] => some content
            [somekey] => some content
            [somekey2] => some content
            [somekey3] => some content
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => some content4
            [subtitle] => some content
            [somekey] => some content
            [somekey2] => some content
            [somekey3] => some content
        )   
)
```

Here's a [working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb08c3d00d6e0446623df7848c995b8c1fabb2fb).

*Note that this only works if your nested arrays all contain the same number of elements and that your array of key values contains the same number of elements (in this case five). Otherwise, you're likely to get a PHP error about "Both parameters should have an equal number of elements".*

---

If you prefer, this can be achieved in one line by using an anonymous function:

```php
array_walk($array,function(&$v,$i,$keys){$v=array_combine($keys,$v);},$keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information.

```
function convertKeys($table) {
    foreach($table as $key => $value) {
        if (0 === $key) {
            $table['title'] = $value;
            unset($table[$key]);
        } else if (1 === $key) {
            $table['subtitle'] = $value;
            unset($table[$key]);
        } else //another mapping
    }
}

foreach($table as $val) {
    //$val is arrray
    convertKeys($val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_combine function within foreach loop. see below example

```
$keys_array = array("title","subtitle","somekey","somekey2","somekey3");
$array=array(
  array('some content','some content','some content','some content','some content'),
  array('some content','some content','some content','some content','some content'),
  array('some content','some content','some content','some content','some content'),
  array('some content','some content','some content','some content','some content'),
  array('some content','some content','some content','some content','some content')
);
$new_array =array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
     $new_array[] = array_combine($keys_array, $value);
}
print_r($new_array);
```